# ng-repeat, ng-click, directive, and controller interaction

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller, angularjs-ng-click

I have this directive snippet:

```
return {
        scope: {},
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'partials/order_table.html',
        controller: 'OrderController as x',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
        }
```

and this `templateURL` snippet:

```
<tr ng-repeat="r in getOrderModel().getSizes()" ng-click="x.setSize($index)">
```

My question is, why is it that the `ng-repeat` has access to the controller directly (`#getOrderModel` is a function in the controller) while `ng-click` does not?  If I remove the hokey `as x` from the directive and the `x.` from the `ng-click`, the `ng-click` stops working.  Why doesn't `ng-click` refer to the controller?  How do I make the controller known to `ng-click` using best practices?

I know `ng-repeat` will create a child scope, but this doesn't feel like a parent scope issue to me.

Comment: If you remove the `as x`, you have to change the implementation in your controller as well. Assign the `setSize()` into `$scope`, not the controller instance `this`.

Answer (score 1):

Use controllerAs property:

```
return {
    scope: {},
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'partials/order_table.html',
    controller: 'OrderController',
    controllerAs: 'x',
    link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
}
```

[AngularJS Documentation for controllerAs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-controlleras-)